# Is there a convention for using self while initializing a class in python?

Tags: python

I'm curious if there is a convention in python for using the self variable in the `__init__` method of a class.

Consider the simple `Person` class.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

        self.fullname = ' '.join([self.firstname, self.lastname])
```

The `__init__` method stores the two inputs `firstname` and `lastname` as instance variables and then uses these instance variables to define the `fullname` instance variable.

It seems like the `self` variable is unnecessary when defining `self.fullname`, so `Person` could alternatively be written as:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

        self.fullname = ' '.join([firstname, lastname])
```

Is there any meaningful difference between these two ways of writing the class? I don't see a difference other than the fact that the second option requires less horizontal space to define `self.fullname`, which might be desirable.

Comment: In your trivial example, no, there is no reason to use `self` when creating `fullname`.  The two produce identical results.

Comment: there's no difference whatsoever in the result, given the assigments just above. I don't see much advantage to writing it the first way, unless you expect you might later change how you assign to `self.firstname` and `self.lastname`.

Comment: The only difference I see is whether you draw the `fullname` components from the input arguments, or from the previously initialized object attributes.  The result is the same.

Comment: If you later decide to normalize the arguments, or provide default values, the first code sample would require less effort to change.  The difference is pretty minimal however: I wouldn't worry about this sort of thing unless it starts to cause problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the word 'self', in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self-in-python)

Comment: Since it wouldn't affect the result, there is no difference in your example. It would be infinitesimally faster not to use the "self." prefix, but probably not enough to matter.

Comment: @deepbhatt this is obviously not a duplicate of the question you've referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example is a (very slightly) more efficient way to write the same code.

In general the methods of an instance use instance variables to maintain the instance's state. Since each method gets the same object as `self`, the different methods can communicate over time through their use.

In both examples `firstname` and `lastname` are so-called "local variables," whose lifetime is only that of the method in which they are bound. Because they can be looked up more quickly (for reasons we needn't go into) as well as easier to type they are usually preferred for values with a limited lifetime.